# Use OpenLayers 4 with Angular 5

Tags: angular, openlayers, angular5

I'm trying to use OpenLayers 4 in Angular 5.

Basically I just want to implement the [QuickStart](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html) example from the official OpenLayers Site.

What I have done so far:

1. `npm install ol --save` to download the ol package
2. [angular-cli.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6w0T.png) added those lines to the angular-cli.json. Saw that this has to be done on another example on Stackoverflow. The ol.css file exists. The ol.js file doesnt. So I don't know if this is the right or the wrong way but it can clearly not work.

My angular project consists of 3 components:

```
 -app
 --console
 --map
 --sidebar

 app.component.css
 app.compinent.html
 app.component.spec.ts
 app.component.ts
 app.module.ts
```

map.component.html

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as ol from '../../../node_modules/ol';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  mapId: string;
  map: ol.Map = undefined;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.map = new ol.Map({
      target: this.mapId,
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM(),
        }),
      ],
      view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([6.661594, 50.433237]),
        zoom: 3,
      })
    });
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell how to get this working correctly?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Edit:** An example with Angular 14 and OpenLayers 7 can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/pzaenger/angular-openlayers).

**Updated to Angular 8.x and OpenLayers 6.x:**

Install `ol` and do the following changes:

1.) Add the accordant CSS in the *html.index* (make sure that the version of the CSS matches the installed version of `ol`) :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
```

Another way is to reference the CSS in the `styles` object within the *angular.json*:

```
"styles": [
  "./node_modules/ol/ol.css",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
```

2.) Create a map in *app.component.ts*:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { defaults as defaultControls } from 'ol/control';

import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
import ZoomToExtent from 'ol/control/ZoomToExtent';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  map: Map;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.map = new Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: 'https://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
          })
        })
      ],
      view: new View({
        center: [813079.7791264898, 5929220.284081122],
        zoom: 7
      }),
      controls: defaultControls().extend([
        new ZoomToExtent({
          extent: [
            813079.7791264898, 5929220.284081122,
            848966.9639063801, 5936863.986909639
          ]
        })
      ])
    });
  }
}
```

3.) Some style in *app.component.css*:

```
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

4.) And finally the markup in *app.component.html*:

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Feel also free to take a look at my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/pzaenger/angular-openlayers).

**Edit:**

As stated by [Bhalchandra Bhosale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55398687/2436655) it might be even better to set the target of the map within `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.map.setTarget('map');
  }
}
```

**Old answer for version 5.2 of `ol`:**

[`ol`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol) is the right package for OpenLayers. However, you do not need to add anything in the *angular-cli.json*.

With the recent update (`"ol": "^5.2.0"`) the way of importing classes and functions of OpenLayers changed a bit.

*map.component.ts*:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import OlMap from 'ol/Map';
import OlXYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
import OlTileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OlView from 'ol/View';

import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  map: OlMap;
  source: OlXYZ;
  layer: OlTileLayer;
  view: OlView;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.source = new OlXYZ({
      url: 'http://tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    });

    this.layer = new OlTileLayer({
      source: this.source
    });

    this.view = new OlView({
      center: fromLonLat([6.661594, 50.433237]),
      zoom: 3
    });

    this.map = new OlMap({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [this.layer],
      view: this.view
    });
  }
}
```

*map.component.html*:

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

*map.component.css*:

```
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Add the CSS of OpenLayers within the `header`-tag of *index.html*:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.1.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<style>html, body { margin: 0; }</style>
```

**Even older answer:**

Your component might look like the following:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import OlMap from 'ol/map';
import OlXYZ from 'ol/source/xyz';
import OlTileLayer from 'ol/layer/tile';
import OlView from 'ol/view';
import OlProj from 'ol/proj';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  map: OlMap;
  source: OlXYZ;
  layer: OlTileLayer;
  view: OlView;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.source = new OlXYZ({
      url: 'http://tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
    });

    this.layer = new OlTileLayer({
      source: this.source
    });

    this.view = new OlView({
      center: OlProj.fromLonLat([6.661594, 50.433237]),
      zoom: 3
    });

    this.map = new OlMap({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [this.layer],
      view: this.view
    });
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. One last question, I'd like to use cusom tiles, so tiles which are stored locally. To archieve this i changed source to OSM. My route is the following "url: './tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'" but i get a 404 Error. Is it because I have to specify a route to tiles with the route service?

Comment: Puh. Sorry, but I can't help about that. Though, your route looks a bit wired.

Comment: For custom tiles, make sure you add ./tiles folder to your angular-cli.json as:  "assets": [
        "assets",
        "tiles"
      ],

Comment: @AlicW This works, but you should not do it this way, because usually you have a lot of tiles. If you then build your app, all tiles are included: the bundle is going to be huge.

Comment: The build process will just keep the same tiles subfolder in the output (build) folder. From what I understand, this is how Giuseppe wants to deploy the app anyway, including custom tiles into the distribution.

Comment: if i only want user current location details (like google geolocation) how can i retrieve it using opengl maps?

Comment: @federer Feel free to [open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: Just a note, I use angular 6 , node 8.11.1, locally on win 10. By using `import OlProj from 'ol/Proj';` I get errors. Replace it with `import * as OlProj from 'ol/proj';` and it will run

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want to start from zero with Angular5 and OpenLayers4, there is a mature project called [IGO2-lib](https://github.com/infra-geo-ouverte/igo2) which is based on `Angular 5.x`, `NodeJS`, `OpenLayers 4.x` and `Material Design`. [IGO2](http://igouverte.org/english/) is also a complete framework.

1. Clone repository using: `git clone https://github.com/infra-geo-ouverte/igo2-lib.git`
2. Deploy in cd igo2-lib/ and install from: `npm install`
3. Start form: `npm start`
4. Open your browser at http://localhost:4200/

Here it is a live demo from [IGO2](http://igouverte.org/english/): https://geoegl.msp.gouv.qc.ca/igo2/apercu-qc/

Comment: Are you affiliated to IGO?

Comment: No, I am more a user of IGO, why?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code into **`ngAfterViewInit()`** instead of `ngOnInit()`

Comment: It's more likely to be comment to Other post