# Cannot get the openlayers css in angular

Tags: css, angular, openlayers, angular6, openlayers-5

I just started using openlayers 5 in my angular 6 and I follow [this tutorial](https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/basics/map.html) and also looking [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283679/use-openlayers-4-with-angular-5).  My angular component right now has

```
import ol-map from 'ol/map';
import ol-xyz from 'ol/source/xyz';
import ol-tile from 'ol/layer/tile';
import ol-view from 'ol/View';
import * as ol-proj from 'ol/proj';
```

in my class

```
 olmap: ol-map;
 source: ol-xyz;
 layer: ol-tile;
 view: ol-view;
```

and then in my `ngOnInit`

```
this.source = new ol-xyz({
  url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.light/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw'
});

this.layer = new ol-tile({
  source: this.source
});

this.view = new ol-view({
  center: ol-proj.fromLonLat([6.661594, 50.433237]),
  zoom: 3,
});

this.olmap = new ol-map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [this.layer],
  view: this.view
});
```

This works but I dont get the styling of the openlayers. I get the zoom buttons as simple, unstyled buttons, under the map `div`. What am I missing here? How can I insert the opelayers css style?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add the OpenLayers stylesheet to the `styles` sections of your `angular.json` file (*this configuration was in `.angular-cli.json` prior to Angular 6*).

**OpenLayers 5/6 Stylesheet**
`node_modules/ol/ol.css`

**OpenLayers 4 Stylesheet**
`node_modules/openlayers/dist/ol.css`

**angular.json**

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "<project name>": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/ol/ol.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            ...
          },
          ...
        },
        ...
        "test": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/ol/ol.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            ...
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```