# Openlayer with angular6 : what will the type script way

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers-5

The recent openlayer is purely developed in typescript.  What will be the architectural approach when developing an angular application together with ol5?

Comment: What do you want to know exactly?

Comment: Maybe my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283679/use-openlayers-4-with-angular-5/48303261#48303261) to _Use OpenLayers 4 with Angular 5_ might help you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be safe to use third-party npm module for this. Have a look at this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-openlayers

Comment: Why would this approach better than using [ol](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol]) directly?

Comment: @pzaenger 1. This will spare you with all the integration issues as it will be handled by the third-party 2. It will reduce the code drastically as you are making/reusing the separate npm module for this 3. Also you are maintaining the modularity of the code.