# How to import openlayers module in Angular using curly braces

Tags: angular, openlayers, angular7

I have an angular 7 Project that includes openlayers.

```
npm install ol
```

So I am using openayers components like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
```

And I am creting a Map object: `var map = new Map(opitons);`

But I want to use curly braces for import modules like this:

```
import {  Map, View } from 'openlayers';
```

But this throws an exception like this:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'openlayers'

Comment: possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48283679/use-openlayers-4-with-angular-5

Comment: `import {Map,View} from 'ol';` ?

Comment: @Mike, the Visual Studio Code redline under variables following:  `[ts] Module '"c:/Users/usr/Desktop/map/ngmap/node_modules/@types/ol/index"' has no exported member 'Map'.`

Comment: You should import from the same source: ol instead of openlayers